# Show that first order Peano's axioms capture the natural numbers regarding satisfiablity

Tags: logic, arithmetic, first-order-logic, axioms, peano-axioms

Denote be $\mathcal P_{MO}$ the set of the [monadic second order axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) of Peano. Then as shown by Dedekind any two model are isomorphic to $\mathbb N$. Hence for a monadic second order sentence we have
$$
 \mathbb N \models \varphi \mbox{ iff } \mathcal P_{MO} \models \varphi
$$
i.e., the natural numbers fullfil $\varphi$ iff every model that fulfills $\mathcal P_{MO}$ also fulfills $\varphi$.

Let $\mathcal P_{FO}$ be the first [order Peano arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) where the monadic induction axiom is replaced by a first order induction scheme over arbitrary predicates.

Let $\psi$ be some first order sentence, then how to show that $\mathcal P_{FO} \models \psi$ implies $\mathbb N \models \psi$? (the other direction is clear, so I am asking about the relation between satisfiability of the axioms vs satisfiability in the natural numbers).

Similar for other first order axiomatization like [Robinson arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic)? The problem is that as mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Models), the first order theories are not categorical.

Comment: "the other direction is clear" The other direction is **false**, since first-order PA isn't complete.

Comment: @NoahSchweber This is not the provability-relation which I would denote by $\vdash$, the notation $\Sigma \models \varphi$ means that every model that satisifies $\Sigma$, also satisfies $\varphi$, and as $\mathbb N$ satisfies $\Sigma = \mathcal P_{FO}$ this gives the mentioned direction...

Comment: @StefanH The completeness theorem for first-order logic says that the relations $\models$ and $\vdash$ (between first-order theories and first-order sentences) are *the same*. The fact that $\mathbb{N}\models \mathcal{P}_{FO}$ means it's clear that $\mathcal{P}_{FO}\models \psi$ implies $\mathbb{N}\models \psi$, not the other way around. And the converse is false, as Noah said, exactly because $\mathcal{P}_{FO}$ is incomplete.

Comment: Got it! Would anyone like to write up a full anwer....

Comment: @StefanH I've done so, finally.

Answer (score 1):

To move this off the unanswered queue:

The fact that $\mathcal{P}_{FO}\models\psi\implies\mathbb{N}\models\psi$ is immediate from the definition of $\models$ *once you know* that $\mathbb{N}\models\mathcal{P}_{FO}$: by definition we have $\mathcal{P}_{FO}\models\psi$ iff every model of $\mathcal{P}_{FO}$ satisfies $\psi$, so since $\mathbb{N}\models\mathcal{P}_{FO}$ we must have $\mathbb{N}\models\psi$.

The other direction meanwhile is false, since $Th(\mathbb{N})$ is complete (every structure's theory is complete) but $\mathcal{P}_{FO}$ is not complete (per Godel - both incompleteness *and* completeness, the latter letting us freely switch between $\vdash$ and $\models$ when applying the former).

---

In general, whenever we have a theory and a model of that theory in mind, think of the theory as a probably-limited-approximation to the model: everything the theory knows is true (about that model), but there are probably lots of things the theory doesn't know.